# How to center a parent div with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Im newbie and learning flexboxes. I can center an element which is inside of parent div but couldn't figure it out centering the PARENT DIV using flexbox.

HTML

```
<div class="center">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 60%;
border: 5px solid #FFFF00;
padding: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Its working great inside the div as expected but I want the div to be centered, not inside of it. How can I do that?
Note: I couldn't find the solution in the other stackoverflow questions.

Update: or what is the best solution for centering  that is responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap that parent element, in another `div` and write that centering code on that wrapper for example like that

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid red
}

.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"><div>
<div>
```

remember when you want to use `flex-box` on element you must use always on parent element not on child